# Parsing date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When i enter the date and submit, the format of my date is `\/06\/12\/1967` and i need in the below format to send my JSON.

The Format Needed With the Slashes to be sent.

```
/Date(1306348200000)/
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be a negative number because it's < 1970 ?

Comment: This question is almost impossible to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date is pre 1970, so you should be able to take advantage of the negative number to represent dates before that.

```
var str = '\/06\/12\/1967',

    date = new Date(str);

str = '/Date(' + +date + ')/';
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/AM2FF/).

If you need it in seconds as opposed to milliseconds, divide by `1000`.

If your date is in the European format (the current date is ambiguous, it could be in either)...

```
var str = '\/06\/12\/1967',

    tokens = str.split('/');

str = [tokens[2], tokens[1], tokens[3]].join('/')

var date = new Date(str);

str = '/Date(' + +date + ')/';
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/AUbyG/).

Comment: Wow, can't expect more.... can you explain me few things... what is tokens[2],tokens[1] etc etc... and why do we add two + +date and can we make it as a general function where i can pass the str and get back...

Comment: @John The `tokens` array is to change the date format if it is not in the US format. The `+` prefix is syntactic sugar for calling the `getTime()` method on the `date` object.