# Parsing the date in MM/DD/YY format

Tags: javascript

I get the response for the Date in this format while showing in the text box, how do i covert it to MM/DD/YYYY and Again re covert it to back to this format while sending

```
/Date(1306348200000)/
```

Comment: What is "this format", ie what date does the `1306348200000` represent?

Comment: below link will solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208847/parsing-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the regExp-like string to a real `Date Object` you could use:

```
var dateNum = Number('/Date(1306348200000)/'.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''))
    , dat = new Date(dateNum); //=>Date {Wed May 25 2011 20:30:00 GMT+0200}
```

To display formatted dates I use my own small [library](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/TmZyh/), which may be of use to you.

Answer (score 4):

```
function dateToString(date) {
    return (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getYear();
}

function dateFromString(str) {
    return new Date(str);
}
```

Note, that month begins from `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = '/Date(1306348200000)/';

// convert to javascript date
var date = new Date(parseInt(s.substr(6, 13))); // removes /Date( & )/

// format the date
function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n; } // leading zeros
var ddmmyy = pad(date.getDate()) + '/' + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2);

// convert back
s = '/Date(' + date.getTime() + ')/';
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can find everything regarding javascript dates http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp