# Cannot find function getMonth in Object 05/06/11

Tags: javascript

Why do i get this error, when i format my date? Code follows below

```
var date = /Date(1306348200000)/

function dateToString(date) {
    return (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getYear();
}

function dateFromString(str) {
    return new Date(str);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who gave you this code [in the first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971756/parsing-the-date-in-mm-dd-yy-format/6971787#6971787) place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define var date  as a regular which can not be accepted by `new Date`,just do it like this.

```
var date = 1312711261103;
```

try it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zhiyelee/wLNSS/

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `date` is a regular expression, not a `Date` object. You probably want:

```
var date = new Date(1306348200000);
```

Also note that calling date `Date` *without* `new` returns a string and not a `Date` object.

*Edit*: Apparently I overlooked the `dateFromString` function, but your code does not show what you do with `date` and how you use these functions. Anyway, it should be clear which value you have to pass to `Date`. Definitely not a regular expression.

Comment: I am passing like this... new Date(/Date(1206348200000/);

Comment: `var date = new Date(1306348200000);`
data => date

Comment: @John: Well, what you do is wrong. You cannot pass a regular expression to `Date`. You have to pass the value. There is no other way. Either you do it as I showed you or you let it be.